# WSUS version compatibility

Tags: windows-server-2016, wsus

Could someone explain WSUS version compatibility? Specifically, if I have Windows Server 2016 and Windows 10, what is the oldest version of WSUS that can update these?
I don't need to upgrade the OS, just install patches/hotfixes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requirements for Windows 10 servicing with WSUS
To be able to use WSUS to manage and deploy Windows 10 feature updates, you must have WSUS 4.0, which is available in the Windows Server 2012 R2 and Windows Server 2012 operating systems. In addition to WSUS 4.0, you must install the KB3095113 and KB3159706 patches on the WSUS server.

Wsus compatibility is basically there to keep you from trying run ancient and EoL OS's. Normally things work ok when you're a version off IE: server 2k12 and 2k16 in the same domain. Or 2k8 and 2k12.